# Will multiple presentViewController method calls throughout the view controllers lead to memory leak in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, presentviewcontroller

I know there has been a lot of discussions occurred related to this topic. But in all discussions all have discussed with 2 view controllers (A&B). My scenario is similar but different.

What will happen when there are multiple view controllers like A,B,C,D. So the presenting flow moves as ,

View controller A (Home) presents View controller B(List). Then from View controller B presents View Controller C (Details).Then from View Controller C presents View Controller D(Advanced Details). Then from View Controller D presents View Controller A , in order to navigate straight to Home !!!

What is the best practice for that ???

Comment: Please give a bit more data on your app structure. Are you using a Navigation Controller? Storyboards? Segues? What is your view hierarchy like? Swift or Obj-C?

Comment: Are you using a `UITabBarController`? That might be useful to present all your view controllers one by one.

Comment: @atulkhatri I am not using TabBar as the design is different.

Comment: @CaptJak I have added more explanations. Hope you will get a clear view.

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing your project structure and details of how you will display A,B,C,D,E,F and then from F back to A, I would take a wild guess and say that it may lead to a memory leak depending on what design patterns you employ to your UIViewControllers. As commented by @CaptJak in your questions, it has hard to tell if, how and when it will cause a memory leak, especially if you use delegation pattern to pass data around view controllers.

Personally, when I do complicated flows such as presenting multiple UIViewControllers and find myself needing to go back a few screens, I will neither pop the views on the stack up until the one I want is on top of the stack (if you are using navigation controller), dismiss view controller if it is presented modally, or unwind segues if I use them. The risk here might be the view controller's memory may have deallocated.

I would have commented but I don't have enough reputation. Take my answer with a grain of salt as I am a still quite fresh in iOS development.

EDIT: Thank you for the details provided in your app flow. Since you could use presentViewController, I am assuming you are running on a NavigationController? If that is the case, I would use `popToViewController` or `popToRootViewController` (if A is your root view controller) for this case instead of presenting A from D again. If A is presented from D again, I am guessing that you will have 2 instances of A in your VC stack which may lead to memory leak.

**PopToViewController method**

```
NSArray arrayOfVCs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
for(UIViewController *currentVC in arrayOfVCs)
{
   if([currentVC isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class])
   {
      [self.navigation.controller popToViewController:currentVC animated:YES]
   }
}
```

**PopToRootViewController method (assuming A is your root view in navigation controller)**

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

**EDIT 12 April 2016**

I have just been thinking about this question so much that I actually did a short RnD on it and just want to share my findings here. I made a crude simple and dirty function to get a stack of all modal view controllers ever presented in my very simple app.

I tested by from A -> B -> C-> B -> C -> B about 20 - 30 times. Everytime I go time B -> C, the memory increased by 0.5MB (because my screens are simple but yours may differ) and ended up increasing from 20+ MB to 50+ MB.

In this function I recorded the number of presented view controllers in the stack and also their names in an array. So far it worked for me but you can give it a try and see if it works for you.

```
//global variables
var vccount = 0
var vcnamelist = [String]()

func getPresentingViewStackCount(currentVC : UIViewController!){
       if(currentVC.presentingViewController != nil){
            vccount = vccount + 1
            let vc = currentVC.presentingViewController
            vcnamelist.append(NSStringFromClass((vc?.classForCoder)!))
            getPresentingViewStackCount(vc)
    }
}

// to use
func someRandomMethod(){
 getPresentingViewStackCount(self)
}
```

Still think its best to use navigation controllers though. It's what they are built for. :)

Comment: I have added more explanations

Comment: I am not using Navigation Controller !

Comment: So all the ViewControllers are presented modally? In that case, I believe you might need to find a way to dismiss the view controllers up until ViewController A. Or you could embed ViewController A in a NavigationController then after you present ViewController D, then call `[self.navigationController dismissViewController:YES]`. A NavigationController is useful when it comes to handling stacks like these.

Comment: what is your conclusion regarding present view controller and memory leak in this scenario

Comment: Well, I am not a pro in this but I have seen scenarios like this. I think eventually it will cause a memory leak because all the VC are still in kept in memory, waiting for the topmost VC to be disposed and come back to it. For example, A -> B -> C -> D -> A -> B -> A, you will have 7 VCs stored in memory (with 3 instances of A and 2 of B). Imagine if the user keeps using the app, you might end up with a LOT of stacked VCs in memory waiting to the topmost to be dismissed. Up to a certain point, the OS will just terminate the app because it is taking too much RAM.

Comment: You can take a look at this article which I found useful when it comes to memory management with presentViewController and pushViewController. http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/ownership-of-presented-view-controllers-with-and-without-arc/

Answer (score 1):

1.If you present like this , A->B->C->D->A,one by one ,on top of each other,you will get an exception:

> Application tried to present modally an active controller

You cannot present a ViewController that is already been presented,just like you cannot push a ViewController that is already in the UINavigationController's stack.

2.If you used Storyboard to build your app, you can use unwind-segue to jump back to A from D.

3.If you used code to build your app , you can keep a weak reference of A in D,and  call

```
[A dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

in ViewController D  as `dismissViewControllerAnimated` let you go back to A.

> -(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^ __nullable)(void))completion;
>   If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it is possible to command + drag from a UIButton (or whatever else you are using to control your flow) to the view controller that you next want to present, so as to navigate properly. Then, you let go and select whatever method of presentation you want, and when you try it, it should work. I am assuming you use XCode for this, and I am not sure for other development applications.

This is designed to prevent a memory leak from occurring, but do note that you will have to create separate files for each separate view controller. Other manual forms of switching may result in memory leaks, depending on the contents of your situation.

Answer (score -3):

Nothing bad if you will display **newly created** A view controller.

Comment: But just think each time when that final action occurs , we are creating a new object of A when already one or more objects are alive !!!!

Comment: It does not matter how many objects you will create until you not use the same objects from view hierarchy.

Comment: So when will those object get deallocated as we are presenting new new objects up on that even the same type (of viewcontrollers)

Comment: If u have a weak reference to Obj A,when u create a new Object of A , previous Obj of A ,should be detached and reference count becomes 0 , that is auto releasable so , so above answer makes sense ,don't why its down voted .
What you can do is , create a poc ,and try pushing modal VC and check in memory consumption in profiler .