# How to dismiss modal view controller if there are multiple view controller are presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a view controller A which has table view and based on row selection, i will open another view controller B modally. I also have inactivity timer implemented for my application. Now when B is presented and A is presenting controller and due to user’s inactivity, another view controller Inactivity View Controller C will be opened modally on top of B. That means i have A , then B on top of A , and C on top of B. Now, user has clicked a button from C to do logout and i am able to dismiss only C. But View Controller B is never dismissed.

Inactivity is implemented using touch event and notifications and notification is presenting inactivityviewcontroller modally on top of current view as mentioned in below code.

```
- (void) applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog(@"Application Did Timeout ...");

    BCDSessionInactivityViewController *sessionView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InactivityViewController"];

    sessionView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    sessionView.preferredContentSize =  CGSizeMake(838,340);
    UIViewController *parentController = self.parentViewController;
    NSLog(@"presenting view controller is %@", [parentController class]);

    [[self topViewController]presentViewController:sessionView animated:YES completion:nil];


}


- (UIViewController *)topViewController{
    return [self topViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}



- (UIViewController *)topViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    if (rootViewController.presentedViewController == nil) {
        return rootViewController;
    }

    if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController *lastViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
        return [self topViewController:lastViewController];
    }

    UIViewController *presentedViewController = (UIViewController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewController:presentedViewController];
}
```

Is there any way i can dismiss controller B also?

In View Controller C method where i m dismissing view controller C, i edit the code as per suggestion, But View Controller B is still not dismissed.

```
- (IBAction)logoutbtn:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"logout is called");
    if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[BCDScanReviewViewController class]] || [[[F7CheckScanner instance]checkFrontScanned] isEqualToString:@"checkFrontScanned"])
         {
             NSLog(@"check front scanned %@",[[F7CheckScanner instance]checkFrontScanned]);
             [[F7CheckScanner instance]scanBackOfCheckNoData];
         }
    [sessionTimer invalidate];
    sessionTimer = nil;
    [[BCDTimeManager sharedTimerInstance]stopIdleTimer];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){

        [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){;
             BCDThankYouViewController  *thankuView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThankyouView"];
             [[self topViewController ]presentViewController:thankuView animated:YES completion:nil];
         }];
    }];



    UIViewController *parentController = self.presentingViewController;
    NSLog(@"presenting view controller is %@", [parentController class]);
   // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
   //     [parentController performSegueWithIdentifier:COMMON_VC_TO_THANK_YOU_VC sender:self];
   // }];


}
```

Comment: Since you are using a NavigationController, you can use the `unwind` segue. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607083/2535467).

Comment: Use completion block of dismissViewControllerAnimated method, in there you can again call dismissViewControllerAnimated for ViewController B.

Comment: @iamyogish; I have edited the questions, its not working as per suggestion. Can you see if i m doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can do from `C` something like,

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ /* do something when the animation is completed */ }];
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ /* do something when the animation is completed */ }];
```

**Update as per comment :**

Replace your

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){

    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){;
         BCDThankYouViewController  *thankuView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThankyouView"];
         [[self topViewController ]presentViewController:thankuView animated:YES completion:nil];
     }];
}];
```

with

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 //you can do something here in completion instead of nil.
```

if you want to dissmiss three viewcontroller then you can use `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController`.

hope this will help :)

Comment: @ Lion : i have below method in Viewcontroller C which dismisses C and here i have added the code as per your comment.But its not dismissing controller B. Can you please look into this? I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss Like this

```
//remove
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for suggestions. i solved this problem with help of other SO posts.Here is solution

```
-(void)dismissModalStack {
    UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
    while (vc.presentingViewController) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController;
    }

    NSLog(@"Dismissing the view controller at root of view hiearchy: %@", [vc class]);

    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
        BCDThankYouViewController  *thankuView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThankyouView"];
        [[self topViewController ]presentViewController:thankuView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```